# Contiguous mutable ordered list

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, data-structures, binary-search-tree

This may or may not exist, but I'm looking for a way of storing a sorted list of integers that's contiguous in memory, reasonably compact, and allows for O(log n) amortized inserts and deletes.  The various self-balancing binary search trees seem to have the insertion and deletion properties I want, but are implemented with pointers all over the place, which doesn't fit my use case very well.  Any ideas?

(The implementation language will almost definitely be C, if it matters.  If there are existing implementations of whatever you propose, all the better, but I'm fine with writing my own.)

Comment: The problem with arrays is that you have to resize the entire array to add new elements as apposed to `malloc`ing a new pointer to an element. It also means you will be allocating more memory than you need to so that you don't unnecessarily resize it too often. (e.g. doubling it's size every time it's full)

So, what exactly is the reason for you needing it? Do you already know the exact size it needs to be at initialization?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment until just now.  They're lists that regularly get compressed and flushed to disk, and later read by other parts of the app.  Reads happen more than writes, and the tasks that read them need to be able to deserialize really quickly, so just taking the contents of the file, decompressing it into ram and using it as-is is ideal.  A separate set of tasks mutates the lists, and at mutation time, the number of ints that will be added or deleted is known from the start, so a sufficiently-large buffer can be allocated to fit both the current list and the new ints.

Comment: Hey have you ever got a solution to this? I think I'm looking for something similar if not mistaken: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295970/is-there-a-flat-contiguous-ordered-map-non-node-based-container-library-in-c

Answer (score 0):

A [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) can be implemented using an [array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays).

Comment: This is true, but I haven't seen a way to implement a BST balance operation for an array-BST that is O(log n), which means I have to either live with it being unbalanced (which means it won't be compact or performant), or sacrifice O(log n) inserts and deletes.

Answer (score 0):

Accroding to the fact that "reads happen more then writes", you can try to use [dynamicaly-resized array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) + [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) on top of it. So, you will get `O(log n)` time access to elements (read), but you have to pay `O(n)` for insert/delete (`O(log n)` - search the proper place in array + `O(n)` - shift elemets to right or left). It is kind of slow, but this is the way how to work it out. Try to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might consider is a [log-structured merge tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_merge-tree). You can store the levels contiguously one after the other, if you keep some metadata about where each level is located. You'd want an array where you can push and pop from the end (like a C++ std::vector).